# Go On Some Page After Submit

Tags: php

I have a page that update the user_points table its call 
`pointsxxl50updateforposts.php`
that automatic update they own user points and
i liked wen its submit the comment to give 50 points after submit is this possible like that because i have try it submit but do nothing
this is what i liked to do something like that

```
<td><input type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Post" onclick="window.location.href='http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/pointsxxl50updateforposts.php'">
  </td>
```

And This Is The Code I Have On That Page with recaptcha option
and i liked to stay with the recaptcha and after submit to go on that page

```
http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/pointsxxl50updateforposts.php
```

```html
<?php
include("db.php");
 
$select=mysql_query("select * from commenttable");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select))
{
 echo "<div id='sty'>";
 echo "<img src='files/fav icon.png'"."' width='50px' height='50px' align='left' />";
 echo "<div id='nameid'>".$row['name']."</div>";
 echo "<div id='msgid'>".$row['message']."</div>";
 echo "</div><br />";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Comment system using php and mysql</title>
<center><br><br><form>
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/home.php'" />
</form></center>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validation()
{
 var nam=document.comment.namename.value;
 var nam1=document.getElementById('tnameid');
 if(nam=="")
 {
  document.comment.namename.focus();
  nam1.style.borderColor="#f00";
  return false;
 }
 var nam1=document.getElementById('tnameid');
 nam1.style.borderColor="";
 var jo=document.comment.job.value;
 var jo1=document.getElementById('tjobid');
 if(jo=="")
 {
  document.comment.job.focus();
  jo1.style.borderColor="#f00";
  return false;
 }
 var jo1=document.getElementById('tjobid');
 jo1.style.borderColor="";
 var mess=document.comment.message.value;
 var mess1=document.getElementById('tmessageid');
 if(mess=="")
 {
  document.comment.message.focus();
  mess1.style.borderColor="#f00";
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center><form name="comment" method="post" action="comment.php" onSubmit="return validation()">

 
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="margin:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td align="right" id="one">Name :<span style="color:#F00;">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="namename" id="tnameid"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" id="one">Work :<span style="color:#F00;">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="job" id="tjobid"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right" id="one"></td>
    <td><textarea name="message" id="tmessageid"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="right" id="one"></td></center>
<?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          // Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "6LfFYRwTAAAAAKjhq4QOgfYXZP6aZ6OSJhNBPglV
";
$privatekey = "6LfFYRwTAAAAAIqSCCYHobymWT98Jwooh9EwinjE";
# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
  <td><input type="submit"  name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Post">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I Just solved the problem by redirect after submit

after the captcha valid response

```html
if ($resp->is_valid) {
               if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
      $name=$_POST['namename'];
      $job=$_POST['job'];
      $message=$_POST['message'];
      $insert=mysql_query("insert into commenttable(name,job,message)values('$name','$job','$message')")or die(mysql_error());
      echo "You posted a comment";
      header("Location: mylink");
```